# Error opening file

Tags: c, file, directory, fopen

## RESOLVED. Problem -

The lecturer uploaded a text file called file.txt and this resulted in a file "file.txt.txt"... I am feeling a mix of frustration and stupidity right now.

---

#### Original problem

I'm having trouble with C using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 trying to open a text file using fopen. I'm not too sure which directory this file.txt should be in so I tried placing it with the .vcxproj file AND the .exe file which is in the Debug directory created by VS.

With no success, I tried including the full path to the file in the fopen function.

This code compiles fine but when I run it, I get an error saying "No such file or directory"

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? I'm really confused here and any help would be most welcome! Thanks in advance.

Code below:

```
int main(void)
{

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("C:\\Directory\\file.txt", "r"); 

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since your program doesn't produce the message 'No such file or directory', I believe that means your IDE is having problems finding the executable you've created, or you have not yet created the executable.  Your code needs to include `<stdio.h>` (I assume it does in fact do so).  Cleanliness would suggest (a) closing the file if you are successful at opening it, and (b) maybe printing a success message if you succeed. FYI: you can use `"C:/Directory/file.txt"` (with forward slashes instead of backslashes) in the API calls, but not on the CMD.EXE command line. That makes writing names easier.

Comment: Instead of editing your title to be "resolved", please post your answer and accept it.  This way, it's very clear that your answer has been found.

Comment: @Makoto: it's a non-reproducible, local problem. Let's close and, hopefully, delete sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the proper header for `fopen()`, which is

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Make sure all the backslashes are really escaped (doubled) in your filename, too.

Comment: "rt" is not conform with C standard

Comment: FWIW, since the OP said that the code compiles fine, I think he is including the right header file.

Comment: I have included the header but not on this question. I shall give the "rt" a go. Thanks

Comment: @user411313 Thanks, I always get confused about that. :) Should have double-checked. Edited, of course.

Comment: @DavidJiang As user411313 pointed out, don't use `"rt"`. I confused the `t` flag with the `b` for binary mode. Text is the default mode, you don't need to specify anything extra to get text mode.

Comment: Ah ok. I double checked that all my backslashes are indeed escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have any file at this place "C:\Directory\file.txt" I guess you do not have one.

I tried the code and it runs perfectly fine for me. Initially I was getting the same error and that was because the file was not there. Once I put the file there, it all worked perfectly as expected.

Please check again that the file is in place.

Comment: Yes I have checked that this is the case. I had the same issue on another computer. The tutor there said it may be a problem with the environment.

Comment: If it is so, it may be a problem with file permissions. (I am not sure though, as you might get a different error in that case). To make sure that it is not the issue, try placing the file in root of the d: drive and check if it is working. If it is so, it is surely the permission issue.